# Include most recent non empty column value in filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

If my data looks like this:

```
Category    Sub Category
1           a
            b
2           c
            d
```

Which shows that there are two categories: "1", which has sub categories "a" and "b", and "2", which has sub categories "c" and "d".

What can I do in excel (for filtering/sorting) to keep rows 1 and 2 together as category "1", instead of the first row as category "1", and the second as category ""?

I'm trying to avoid having to do this:

```
Category    Sub Category
1           a
1           b
2           c
2           d
```

Comment: Can't avoid it, if you have row based data you have to repeat common keys across rows.  HOWEVER you don't always have to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge cells, and that will work for filtering.
For instance, if your data is in range `A1:B5`, you would merge cells `A2:A3`, and `A4:A5`.
Then you can filter by column B, and the values in column A will work for the two corresponding rows.

Merging cells in this way will not work for sorting, though. For this case, you could write some brief VBA code. A brief pseudocode follows:

```
for irow2 = 0 to nrows/2-1
  A<2*irow2+1>.Value = A<2*irow2>.Value
next irow2
Range(A2:B<nrows+1>).Sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.....if you have a column with **1**'s and then **2**'s, etc.  Format the first **1** normally.  Format all the other **1**'s below with the text color the same as the cell background color.

Thus only the top **1** will appear to have a value.  The other **1**'s will appear empty.

Similar with the **2**'s.

This gets you your desired visual effect and still supports filtering.